# Plotting Band Structure for Kagome lattice along high symmetry direction in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to Plot Band Structure for Kagome lattice along high symmetry direction(Gamma-K-M-Gamma) in Python. I am using the same lattice vectors and reciprocal lattice vectors as Graphene structure.

I tried to plot with these parameter, but I don't get desired result. It looks like my high symmetry points positions are not true. But I solved with pythtb package with the same parameters, there I get desired result. Can anyone help me find out what wrong is happenning in my code.

Both my code and pythtb code (along with plot picture is given below). The pythtb plot is the correct one.

Kagome material has 3 sublattices(A,B,C).
 [The lattice vectors, reciprocal lattice vectors, positions of the high symmetry points and connectimg vectors of sublattices.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5Y6N.png)

**My code-**

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
kx, ky = sp.symbols('kx ky')

def Pab(kx, ky):
    return 2*sp.cos( ((sp.sqrt(3) * kx) / 2) + ky / 2)

def Pbc(kx, ky):
    return 2*sp.cos(ky)

def Pac(kx, ky):
    return 2* sp.cos(((sp.sqrt(3) * kx) / 2 - ky / 2))

def CPab(kx, ky):
    return 2*sp.cos( ((sp.sqrt(3) * kx) / 2) + ky / 2)

def CPbc(kx, ky):
    return 2*sp.cos(ky)

def CPac(kx, ky):
    return 2* sp.cos(((sp.sqrt(3) * kx) / 2 - ky / 2))
Ea=0;Eb=0;Ec=0
tab=1;tbc=1;tca=1
H=sp.Matrix([[Ea , -tab* CPab(kx,ky), -tca* CPac(kx,ky)],
             [-tab* Pab(kx,ky), Eb, -tbc*CPbc(kx,ky)],[-tca*Pac(kx,ky), -tbc*Pbc(kx,ky),Ec]])
numeric_H = sp.lambdify((kx, ky), H, "numpy")

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
a=1
d1=(4*np.pi)/(3*np.sqrt(3)*a)

y1= (2*np.pi)/(3*np.sqrt(3)*a)
x1= (2*np.pi)/(3*a)
k1=[];k2=[];k3=[]
E1=[];E2=[];E3=[];En1=[];En2=[];En3=[];Ep1=[];Ep2=[];Ep3=[]
stepsizey = y1/500

#For Gamma to K path
kx=0
while kx<= x1:
    ky= kx/np.sqrt(3)
    k1.append(np.sqrt(kx**2+ky**2))
    numeric_matrix = numeric_H(kx, ky)
    eigenvalues = np.linalg.eigvals(numeric_matrix)
        
    E1.append(eigenvalues[0].real)
    En1.append(eigenvalues[1].real)
    Ep1.append(eigenvalues[2].real)
    kx+= stepsizey

#For K to M path
while ky >=0 :
    kx= x1
    k2.append(np.sqrt((kx-x1)**2+(ky-y1)**2))
    numeric_matrix = numeric_H(kx, ky)
    eigenvalues = np.linalg.eigvals(numeric_matrix)
        
    E2.append(eigenvalues[0].real)
    En2.append(eigenvalues[1].real)
    Ep2.append(eigenvalues[2].real)
    ky-= stepsizey
d2 =-( k2[0]-k2[len(k2)-1])


k2r =[]
for i in range (len(k2)):
    k2r.append(k2[i]+d1)
    i+=1

#For M to Gamma path

while kx>=0:
    ky=0
    k3.append(np.sqrt((x1-kx)**2))
    numeric_matrix = numeric_H(kx, ky)
    eigenvalues = np.linalg.eigvals(numeric_matrix)
        
    E3.append(eigenvalues[0].real)
    En3.append(eigenvalues[1].real)
    Ep3.append(eigenvalues[2].real)
    kx-= stepsizey
k3r=[]
for i in range (len(k3)):
    k3r.append(k3[i]+d1+d2)
#plotting

plt.scatter(k1,E1,color='r', s=1)
plt.scatter(k2r,E2,color='r', s=1)
plt.scatter(k3r,E3,color='r', s=1)
plt.scatter(k1,En1,color='r', s=1)
plt.scatter(k2r,En2,color='r', s=1)
plt.scatter(k3r,En3,color='r', s=1)
plt.scatter(k1,Ep1,color='r', s=1)
plt.scatter(k2r,Ep2,color='r', s=1)
plt.scatter(k3r,Ep3,color='r', s=1)
plt.axvline(x=d1, color='b', linestyle='--', label='K')
plt.axvline(x=0, color='b', linestyle='--', label='K')
plt.axvline(x=d1+d2, color='b', linestyle='--', label='K')
plt.axvline(x=k3r[len(k3r)-1], color='b', linestyle='--', label='K')
custom_tick_positions = [0, d1, d1+d2, k3r[len(k3r)-1]]
custom_labels = ['$\Gamma$', 'K', 'M','$\Gamma$' ]
plt.xticks(custom_tick_positions, custom_labels)
plt.show()
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZFI9.png)

**Pythtb code-(Reference-Topological properties of flat bands in generalized Kagome lattice materials,
Daniela Pinto Dias)**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function  # python3 style print

# Tight-binding 2D Kagome Lattice

from pythtb import *  # import TB model class
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set model parameters
E = 0.  # on-site energy
t = -1.0  # spin-independent first-neighbor hop


def set_model(E, t):
    # Set up Kagome model
    lat = [[np.sqrt(3.0) / 2.0, -0.5], [np.sqrt(3.0) / 2.0, 0.5]]
    orb = [[0., 0.], [1. / 2., 0.], [0., 1. / 2.]]
    model = tb_model(2, 2, lat, orb, nspin=2)
    model.set_onsite([E, E, E])

    # Spin-independent first-neighbor hops
    # Atom A hopping terms
    model.set_hop(t, 1, 0, [0, 0])
    model.set_hop(t, 1, 0, [1, 0])

    # Atom B hopping terms
    model.set_hop(t, 2, 1, [0, 0])
    model.set_hop(t, 2, 1, [-1, 1])

    # Atom C hopping terms
    model.set_hop(t, 0, 2, [0, 0])
    model.set_hop(t, 0, 2, [0, -1])
    return model, orb


# Print tight-binding model
my_model, orb = set_model(E, t)
my_model.display()

# Generate list of k-points following a segmented path in the BZ
# List of nodes (high-symmetry points) that will be connected
path = [ [0., 0.], [2. / 3., 1. / 3.], [0.5,0.5],[0.,0.]]
# Labels of the nodes
label = (r'$\Gamma$', r'$K$', r'$M$', r'$\Gamma$')

# Total number of interpolated k-points along the path
nk = 121

# Call function k_path to construct the actual path
(k_vec, k_dist, k_node) = my_model.k_path(path, nk)
# Inputs:
# path, nk: see above
# my_model: the pythtb model
# Outputs:
# k_vec: list of interpolated k-points
# k_dist: horizontal axis position of each k-point in the list
# k_node: horizontal axis position of each original node

print('---------------------------------------')
print('starting calculation')
print('---------------------------------------')
print('Calculating bands...')

# Obtain eigenvalues to be plotted
evals = my_model.solve_all(k_vec)

# Figure for band structure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Specify horizontal axis details
# Set range of horizontal axis
ax.set_xlim(k_node[0], k_node[-1])
# Put tick marks and labels at node positions
ax.set_xticks(k_node)
ax.set_xticklabels(label, size=22)
ax.tick_params(axis="y", labelsize=22)
# Add vertical lines at node positions
for n in range(len(k_node)):
    ax.axvline(x=k_node[n], linewidth=0.5, color='k')
# Put labels
ax.set_xlabel("Path in k-space", size=22)
ax.set_ylabel("Band energy", size=22)

# Plot bands
for i in range(2 * len(orb)):
    ax.plot(k_dist, evals[i], color='r')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[pythtb result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1OMP.png)